# Difference between callback versus promise approach with redis set example

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working with the node-redis library, which seems to be using a promise approach. Some old articles (2021) I have been following use an older callback approach.

I am curious about the difference between

```
client.set('Foo', 'Bar', function(err, reply) {
  console.log(reply);
  // Follow on logic using reply

});
```

and

```
let reply = await client.set('Foo', 'Bar');
// Follow on logic using reply
```

What reasoning is there to use promises instead now?

Comment: Promises are simply a more modern coding style.

Comment: When you have lots of callbacks, you end with heavily nested functions if you use callbacks. `async/await` allows you to write code in a style that looks synchronous, which is easier to read and write.

Comment: `What reasoning`,  Eh!!  doesn't the `await` one look much nicer to you?, it becomes even more relevant when you want the result from one callback to go to another, but here your example is not really showing the benefits.  Oh, and handling errors in callback is even harder, with `async / await`, `try / catch` works as expected.